# Getting undefined in javascript when calling ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, undefined

```
function get_request(url) {
  var request = new getXMLObject();
  request.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
      alert(request.responseText);
      var data = eval('(' + request.responseText + ')');
      alert(data);
      return data;
    }   
  }
  request.open("GET", url, true);
  //alert(document.getElementById('energy').innerHTML);
  request.send();
}

function loadjobs() {
  var url = "loadjobs.php?tab=1&id=1111";
  //var data=
  //alert(check());
  alert(get_request(url));
  //alert(data);
}
```

When i m getting data in json format...i am gettin `NULL` in `alert(get_request(url));`
while i m getting in `alert(data);`

Help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the request in asynchronous . The `get_request(url)` function does to return anything and hence the null ( although I think it should be undefined and not null ) .

The `onreadystatechange` function gets called later in the time , when the AJAX request has been completed and the data is returned from the server and hence the alert there works .

Answer (score 0):

This is a misunderstanding of how AJAX works. Ajax is *asynchronous*. The `onreadystatechange` function will be called *after* `loadjobs()`. The "return path" you are specifying can never work. `get_request()` will never be able to return the fetched value.

You have two options. Either make the script synchronous - this can be done but is not recommended because it can freeze the browser.

Or, better, handle everything you need to do inside the `onreadystatechange`  callback.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Ajax requests work **asynchronously**. So you can't return the data right away. The way you should do it is to specify a **callback function** which will handle the response data.

```
function handleJSON( data ) {
  // ...
  // do whatever you want to do with the data
}

ajax( "url/file.php?param=value", handleJSON );

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function getXmlHttpObject() {
    var xmlHttp;
    try {
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e) {
        try {
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
    }
    return xmlHttp;
}

function ajax(url, onSuccess, onError) {
    var xmlHttp = getXmlHttpObject();
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4) {
            // onError
            if (this.status != 200) {
                if (typeof onError == 'function') {
                    onError(this.responseText);
                }
            }
            // onSuccess
            else if (typeof onSuccess == 'function') {
                onSuccess(this.responseText);
            }
        }
    };
    xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlHttp.send(null);
    return xmlHttp;
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's an **asynchronous** call. You will receive the data of request your **after** `get_request` has already returned. That means your `request.onreadystatechange = function ()` will be executed long after `alert(get_request(url));` is already finished. This means `get_request` will not be able to return any data from the AJAX call. That's what you have the `request.onreadystatechange` callback function for, to execute code at an undefined later time when you received the response.